Find all holomorphic $f$ on $\mathbb C$ such that $f\circ f(z)=2f(z)-z$
I encountered this unsourced exercise on differentiable functions $f :\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for any real $x$, $f\circ f(x)=2f(x)-x$. I found it not straightforward to prove that these are $f : x\mapsto x+c$ for any real $c$. My proof strongly relies on the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ and can't be transposed to address the problem in $\mathbb C$. To see that here are the main steps I used :
such $f$ is injective and continuous so it is strictly monotonic. So $f\circ f$ is strictly increasing and so is $f$ from $2f(x)=f\circ f(x)+x$. Supposing $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=l$ with $l\in\mathbb R$ leads to the contradiction $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f\circ f(x)=-\infty$, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ and likewise $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. From the relation we get $f'(x)(2-f'(f(x))=1$ so $0<f'<2$ and then $f'>1/2$. Let $\alpha=\inf_{x\in\mathbb R}f'(x)$ and $\beta=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}f'(x)$ : $1/2\leqslant \alpha\leqslant \beta\leqslant 2$ and $\alpha$ is also $\inf_{x\in\mathbb R}f'(f(x))$, $\beta=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}f'(f(x))$ so, because $f'(f(x))=2-1/f'(x)$ we get $\alpha=2-1/\alpha$ and $\beta=2-1/\beta$. This entails $\alpha=\beta=1$ so $f'(x)=1$ and we are done.
Obviously very little of it can be used to answer the question in $\mathbb C$, I've tried but didn't manage to prove that $f$ must be of the kind $f(z)=z+c$ for a fixed $c\in\mathbb C$ neither found I a counter example, though for any differentiable non-constant $c : ]-\pi;\pi[\rightarrow \mathbb R$ we have $f : z=re^{i\theta}\mapsto z+c(\theta)$ that satisfies the relation and is holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R_-$ but it can't be extended into a holomorphic function on all of $\mathbb C$ (if I'm not wrong, considering my little knowledge of holomorphic functions I might). I would very much appreciate any insight on that question, I'm very curious to know whether there is a proof in $\mathbb C$ or a counter-example.

You get injectivity also in the complex case. An entire injective fuction is of the form $f(z)=az+b$ with $a\not=0$, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964534/proving-that-all-entire-and-injective-functions-take-the-form-f-ax-b

Many thanks, that answers the question!
